# Integrating Qt with WinForms to use certain classes

Tags: c++, winforms, qt, visual-c++

So I'm writing a Windows Form Application using C++, I wanted to use the [QtRubberBand Class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qrubberband.html). Without having to redo the whole application in Qt, is this possible to do? How can I do this? Or is there an alternative that doesn't rely on Qt?

Comment: Based on the link you provided, I believe you could use [ControlPaint::DrawReversibleFrame Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlpaint.drawreversibleframe(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1).

Comment: You cannot write a Windows Forms application in C++. Impossible to give advice, when you aren't capable of presenting your problem.

Comment: @IInspectable How is it impossible? I simply downloaded a template that allowed me to do so. I can design and use the standard controls same as a C# or VB.NET program.

Comment: You can write a Windows Forms application in C++/CLI very easily.

Comment: C++/CLI is not C++. You cannot write a Windows Forms application using C++. Which part are you confused about?

Comment: @IInspectable Why is it not C++? Which part are you confused about?

Comment: @TnTinMn Thanks for the link. If you can make that into an answer I can accept it. :)

Comment: C++/CLI compiles to IL (the part that talks to Windows Forms anyways). This is **not** C++. If you cannot properly represent your problem, why are you even asking? And why are you arguing against logic? And while we're at it: What does *"QuickTime"* have to do with any of this?

Comment: @IInspectable You need to stop nitpicking use of terminology. https://www.qt.io/ Who said anything about quick time?

Comment: Uhm... like, you did? That link takes you to Qt. Qt has nothing to do with QT. And frankly, telling you that C++/CLI is not C++ is nitpicking? In what universe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ControlPaint::DrawReversibleFrame Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlpaint.drawreversibleframe(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1) appears to give the same function as QRubberBand Class.